# Latency in TCP is Round Trip Time(RTT) or one way time

Tags: tcp, latency

I would like to know how the latency in TCP communication is calculated. Is it the Round Trip Tme(RTT) i,e the time between the sending of message to the reciever and the time of reception of acknowledgement at the sender. Or one way time that is sending the message from the sender to the reciever.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

It's neither. It's the time between when data is sent by the application on one side and is received by the application on the other side. It must be at least the one way time. But depending on what's going on with the TCP protocol itself, it can include the time it takes an acknowledgement to go the other way or the time it takes certain TCP timers to expire.